# Set input value before onClick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Group of Radio button with different values, I'm trying to call a function based on the value of the input.

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified " data-toggle="buttons" name="chartSelect">
   <label class="btn btn-info"  onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="" type="radio">All
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="total" type="radio">Total
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="max" type="radio">Max
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="mean" type="radio">Mean
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="min" type="radio">Min
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart()">
     <input name="chart" value="extrapolation" type="radio">Extrapolation
   </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function getChart() {
    var startDate = $('#range').val().slice(0, 10) + 'T' + $('#range').val().slice(11, 16) + ':00+00:00';
    var endDate = $('#range').val().slice(19, 29) + 'T' + $('#range').val().slice(30, 38) + ':00+00:00';
    var appName = $('select[name=applicationSelect]').val();
    var envName = $('input[name=env]:checked').val();
    var chartType = $('input[name=chart]:checked').val();
    // Load chart
    ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate, appName, envName, chartType);
};

// Function for loading data via AJAX and showing it on the chart
function ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate, appName, envName, chartType) {
    // If no data is passed (the chart was cleared)
    if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise, issue an AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://MyServlet.com',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate,
            env: envName,
            app: appName,
            type: chartType
        },
        success: function (data) {
            defaultChart(data);
        }
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + " " + error);
        console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is value of the selected input is set after the function has been called so the previous selected value is fetched in the Ajax request.

I'm new to JS, can I fix this without massive changes to my code?

Comment: bind it to onChange event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the code now, the function *getChart* will be executed twice on every click, because the event is fired for both the `input` element and the `label` element. Which is the checked radio button at the time of these events is different for these two cases.

But you'd anyway want to avoid a double call, as you'll want to do your Ajax calls only when necessary.

I would advise to make these changes:

- First remove the `onclick` attributes from all `input` tags;
- Wrap the *getChart* function inside `$('[name=chart]').change(...)`. This makes it the change event handler for all these chart `input`s in one go.

Here is the result (testable):

```js
$('[name=chart]').change(function getChart() {
    var chartType = $('input[name=chart]:checked').val();
    // just for testing:
    alert('Choice = ' + chartType);
    // rest of your getChart function follows here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form"> 
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified " data-toggle="buttons" name="chartSelect">
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="" type="radio">All
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="total" type="radio">Total
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="max" type="radio">Max
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="mean" type="radio">Mean
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="min" type="radio">Min
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input name="chart" value="extrapolation" type="radio">Extrapolation
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I kept the name of the function *getChart*, but the function can be anonymous as it is being used here.

Comment: I had to modify your code slightly to work with mine, but this is what I wanted to do, I though it was a bad idea to be calling the onClick() the way I had, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad to see you appreciate this way of coding.

Answer (score 1):

set the parameter to the function

```
function getChart(param){
alert(param);
}
```

and then give it to the event,

```
<label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart(20)">
  <input name="chart" value="mean" type="radio">Mean
</label>
<label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart(25)">
  <input name="chart" value="mean" type="radio">Mean
</label>
```

It can be String value too, just give quote on the event

```
<label class="btn btn-info" onclick="getChart('mean')">
  <input name="chart" value="mean" type="radio">Mean
</label>
```

It will show the value of getChart into an alert. Sorry for bad english, I'm Erwin from Indonesia, hope this will help you :D

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have onClick handler on the label, and not the input field.

Also it might be easier to extract values from input fields once any of them change using jQuery ala $('[type=input]').change(function(){
// extract all field values and call Ajax to retrieve new chart 
});

Answer (score 1):

Without significant changes to the existing code, you should simply let the event propagate before calling your `getChart`. Change the function name of `getChart` to `getChart_` and create a new function like so: `function getChart() { setTimeout(getChart_, 0); }`.

What we're doing here is scheduling the original `getChart` call to happen after the event handler has been executed (and state of the input updated).